# Sorting table by its column value in Twig

Tags: symfony, twig

I created a method in Twig that will count and display results in table.But I want to sort the table based on results column

```
{% for island in islands %} 
        <tr>
            <td>{{ island.id }}</td>
            <td>{{ island.name }}</td>
            <td>{{ number_votes(island.id) }}</td>
        </tr>
{% endfor %}
```

results

```
  id  name   result
  1   name1  3000
  2   name2  100
  3   name3  5000
  4   name4  90
```

As you can see it is sorted by default based on its id.How to sort based on its result column?

My twig filter

```
public function getFunctions()
{
return array(

  new \Twig_SimpleFunction('number_votes', array($this, 'a'))
 );
 }

 public function getName()
 {
 return 'app.extension';
 }   

 public function a($id)
 {
 $qb=$this->em->createQueryBuilder();
 $qb->select('count(v.id)')
  ->from('Bundle:Voters','v')
  ->join('v.city','c')
  ->join('c.province','p')
  ->join('p.region','r')
  ->join('r.island','i')
  ->where('i.id = :x')
  ->setParameter('x',$id);
  $count = $qb->getQuery()->getSingleScalarResult(); 
  return $count;
  //I tried return sort($count)//not working
  }
```

I also tried

```
{{ number_votes(island.id)|sort }}/throws an error
```

I'm afraid I have to create another Twig filter,is there any way to prevent this?

Comment: I stumbled upon this problem in the past, and I used this jQuery plugin (maybe it's not relevant for your particular pb) : http://joequery.github.io/Stupid-Table-Plugin/ It allows you to sort your tables based on each column values. Of course it's client side, so it doesn't answer fully your question...

Comment: I will try this solution.It doesn't t matter if its client side as long as the tables is sorted based on column values

Answer (score 1):

You could avoid a twig filter completely and do something like this so you have your islands and your vote counts in one result set:

```
    $islandsAndVotes = $qb->select('i, count(v.id) as vote_count')
        ->from('Bundle:Voters','v')
        ->join('v.city','c')
        ->join('c.province','p')
        ->join('p.region','r')
        ->join('r.island','i')
        ->groupBy('i')
        ->orderBy('vote_count', 'DESC')
        ->getQuery()
        ->getResult()
    ;
```

Each element of $islandsAndVotes will contain an Island entity at index 0 and a vote count at index 1

E.g.

```
foreach ($islandsAndVotes as $islandVote) {

    $island = array_shift($islandVote);
    $votecount = array_shift($islandVote);
}
```

In twig you could use [first](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/filters/first.html) & [last](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/filters/last.html) to access the island or the vote count respectively as you iterate over the results.

```
{% for islandVote in islandsAndVotes %}
    {% set island = islandVotes|first %}
    {% set voteCount = islandVotes|last %}
    <tr>
        <td>{{ island.id }}</td>
        <td>{{ island.name }}</td>
        <td>{{ voteCount }}</td>
    </tr>
{% endfor %}
```